# Текст в сохраненный в mysql обрезается

Tags: mysql

Через POST идет запрос в PHP, где выполняется запись в БД, но текст обрезается и ставится многоточие, формат столбца TEXT[формат столбца TEXT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbM7K.png)[image: обрезанный текст]

Comment: MySQL может обрезать при определённых условиях... но он НИКОГДА не добавит троеточие.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, смотрите свой код, который на сервере. Там наверняка какая-то функция предварительно обрезает текст до вставки (или до вывода пользователю...в зависимости где вы обнаружили этот обрезанный текст).

Comment: ради эксперимента добавил текст в mysql напрямую, через запрос в myadmin - результат тот же

Comment: Есть предположение, что вы смотрите вывод в phpmyadmin, конечно он не будет показывать весь текст. Если нажать на ячейку например для редактирования, наверняка он покажет его весь

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/762886)

Comment: @NowhereMan ещё как является ответом.